# How to generate hash if password starts with "-" using openssl in powershell?

Tags: powershell, openssl

I want to generate a SHA512 hash in powershell using openssl.
Unfortunately powershell interprets my password as an option because it starts with "-".

I tried the following:

```
$test="-test"
& "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe" passwd -6 "$test"
```

.. and got the following error:

```
openssl.exe : passwd: Unknown option: -test
```

Comment: Try: `& "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe" passwd -6 """$test"""` or `... -- $Test`, see [About Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing).

Comment: Does not work. Got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Little workaround:

Use a file as cache and try adding the option -in to the openssl command like so:

```
$test="-test"
$cachefile = "C:\Script\cache.txt"
$test | Out-File -FilePath $cachefile -NoNewline

& "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe" passwd -6 -in $cachefile
```